# Static properties in one class set by another

Tags: php, inheritance, static, prepared-statement

I've been working on a small set of classes in PHP 5.3.x that follow the Active Record pattern. I'm running to an issue, however, when working with static properties. Here's the bit of code I've been testing this with:

```
<?php

class dbPreparedObject {

    public static $insert = "";

    public function __construct() {
        static::$insert = "autoinsert_".get_called_class();
    }
}

class gtRecord extends dbPreparedObject {}
class nRecord extends dbPreparedObject {}

$a = new gtRecord();
$b = new nRecord();

var_dump(gtRecord::$insert);
var_dump(nRecord::$insert);
```

Output:

```
string(18) "autoinsert_nRecord"
string(18) "autoinsert_nRecord"
```

I, however, expect the first string to read `autoinsert_gtRecord`.

It seems that static properties that aren't instantiated by the child class are tied together. Is there any way to separate them without declaring `public static $insert = ""` in every child class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.  In PHP, properties declared static are shared amongst all instances of the object created.  That is, there is only one instance of `$insert` across all instances of of `dbPreparedObject` or its inherited classes.

The reason you are seeing `autoinsert_nRecord` for both `var_dump`s is because that was the last object you created.

Consider this minor change:

```
$a = new gtRecord();
var_dump(gtRecord::$insert); // autoinsert_gtRecord

$b = new nRecord();    
var_dump(nRecord::$insert);  // autoinsert_nRecord
var_dump(gtRecord::$insert); // autoinsert_nRecord (because it was the last one set)
```

After the first var_dump, the value is `_gtRecord`, but once an `nRecord` object is created, the static property gets changed (for all dbPreparedObject objects) to be `nRecord` since that was the last class.

So if you plan on having multiple instances of this class, `$insert` cannot be static because it will not always contain the value you expect given the code since there is only one copy of the static `$insert` property that is the same for all objects.  Once you change it in one object, you change it in all objects.

So we need to ask why `$insert` needs to be static or what other options to you have so you don't run into this issue.

Comment: I guess my question then is how do I define properties that should be inherited by a class without explicitly defining them in the class declaration?

Comment: If a property is public or protected, it will be inherited by any child classes without defining them in the subclasses.

Comment: It just seems strange to me that if I change an inherited properly within a child class, that it would affect that inheritance in other child classes. Why would a property of a child class, inherited or not, affect the parent class?

Comment: It only does if it is static, because a static property only has one instance that is shared among all instances of the class (and its children).

Comment: Is there a way to define a class property without the `static` keyword?

Comment: Yes, the normal non-static way is like this: `class Foo { public $bar; public $baz = 'value'; }`  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php  Properties declared like this cannot be accessed without creating a concrete instance of the class, and you reference them using `$obj->property` or `$this->property` if you are within the class.